# Writing matrices from systems of equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How could I write the following system in matrix form,

\begin{equation}
F_i + \sum ^N_{j=1} (f_{ij} - g_{ij})x_j = 0 \qquad \text{where} \qquad F_i = a_i + \sum ^n_{k=1}c_i^kb^k
\end{equation}
My attempt is as follows, 
\begin{equation}
\vec x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_N\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\vec B = \begin{pmatrix} f_{11} - g_{11} & \dots & f_{1N} - g_{1N}  \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
f_{N1} - g_{N1} & \dots & f_{NN} - g_{NN}\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

But I can't quite write $F_i$. Would that matrix contain other matrixes for the sum over $k$?

Comment: Is or not $N=n$?

Comment: @RafaBudría No they are not the same $N\neq n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need in this expression a matrix inside another matrix. It's a vector. And it doesn't matter that $C$ is not a square matrix (it's a $n\times N$ matrix), because it's multiplied by a vector of dimension $n$ to produce a vector of dimension $N$

$$\vec F=\vec a+C\vec b$$

Then

$$\vec a+C\vec b+B\vec x=0$$

It is as simple as it seems. Maybe you need to write the form of the matrix $C$ and of the vector $\vec b$:

$$\begin{equation}
\vec b = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$$

$$\begin{equation}
C = \begin{pmatrix} c_1^1 & \dots & c_1^n  \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
c_N^1 & \dots & c_N^n\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$$